# Toggle between two divs, reset once opened

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons called "About Me" and "Projects". I've made so that no matter which button I click, they both have their own content that shows "in the same place". (switches between divs)

I also implemented that you can toggle between show or not showing content once clicked on one of the buttons. However, my problem is that I want to be able to switch between "About Me" and "Projects" and ALWAYS show their content (when I switch between those two), and only hide their content when I click twice on the same button

I think that the problem is in my toggle functions, so I'll just paste the code here. Hopefully someone understands my problem.

```
function toggleAbout() {
var showAbout = document.getElementById("aboutBtn");
var hideAbout = document.getElementById("aboutDiv");

showAbout.addEventListener('click', function () {
    hideAbout.classList.toggle("show");
  });
}

function toggleproject() {
var showproject = document.getElementById("projectBtn");
var hideproject = document.getElementById("projectDiv");

showproject.addEventListener('click', function () {
     hideproject.classList.toggle("show");
   });
 }
```

Functions calls are made in index.html

```
<button id="aboutmeBtn" class="btn" onclick="toggleAbout()"> About Me   </button>
<button id="ProjectBtn" class="btn" onclick="toggleproject()"> Project</button>
```

Comment: Can you include where your calling `toggleAbout` and `toggleproject` from? I'm guessing your calling them when you click the buttons but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I call them in my html file. I've included them in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @JO3-W3B-D3V solution is a bit complicated so I'll try and answer differently.

I think your problem is that your running the `addEventListeners` when you click on the buttons but it should run when the page gets loaded instead.

Also I took out the toggle and instead changed the classes by hand if it's shown or hidden.

Try this:

```js
var showAbout   = document.getElementById("aboutBtn");
var hideAbout   = document.getElementById("aboutDiv");
var showproject = document.getElementById("projectBtn");
var hideproject = document.getElementById("projectDiv");

showAbout.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (hideAbout.classList == 'hide') {
        hideAbout.classList = 'show';
        hideproject.classList = 'hide';
    } else {
        hideAbout.classList = 'hide';
        hideproject.classList = 'hide';
    }
});

showproject.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (hideproject.classList == 'hide') {
        hideproject.classList = 'show';
        hideAbout.classList = 'hide';
    } else {
        hideproject.classList = 'hide';
        hideAbout.classList = 'hide';
    }
});
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#yourApp div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

#aboutDiv {
  background-color: pink;
}

#projectDiv {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#aboutBtn {
  background-color: pink
}

#projectBtn {
  background-color: dodgerblue
}
```

```html
<div id="yourApp">
  <div id='aboutDiv' class='show'>About</div>
  <div id='projectDiv' class='hide'>Project</div>
  
  <button id="aboutBtn">About</button>
  <button id="projectBtn">Project</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree, but I wasn't 100% sure what he wanted... So I thought heyho, give him as much as possible!?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry I didn't read the question properly, just editing it now

Comment: Hey, no worries Mike, I mean I know my solution is a little overly engineered for the problem at hand, but at least it could scale to some extent, haha.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Is this the *kinda* thing you're after? ...

```js
!function () {
  var aboutBtn = document.getElementById("aboutBtn");
  var projectBtn = document.getElementById("projectBtn");
  var aboutPage = document.getElementById("aboutDiv");
  var projectPage = document.getElementById("projectDiv");

  // The class name for visible elements.
  var showState = 'show';

  // The class name for hidden elements.
  var hideState = 'hide';

  // Boolean value to state if you wish to
  // automatically toggle between
  // the two elements.
  var toggle = false;

  // Forces the other element to be hidden.
  var hideOther = true;


  // Simply states if the provided element
  // is visible or not.
  var isVisible = function (el) {
    return el.className.toLowerCase().indexOf(showState) >= 0;
  };

  // Simple method to swap the visibility
  // state.
  var swapState = function (el, oel) {
    if (isVisible(el)) el.className = hideState;
    else el.className = showState;

    if (oel != null)
      if (el.className === showState) oel.className = hideState;
      else oel.className = showState;
  };

  var controller = function (el) {
    var me, other;

    // Simply workout which button has been pressed.
    if (el.getAttribute('id') === projectBtn.getAttribute('id')) {
      me = projectPage;
      other = aboutPage;
    } else {
      me = aboutPage;
      other = projectPage;
    }

    // If toggle is false.
    if (!toggle) swapState(me);
    else swapState(me, other);

    // Both wouldn't really work together,
    // at least to my knowledge.
    if (hideOther && !toggle) other.className = hideState;
  };

  // Simply bind the event handler.
  aboutBtn.addEventListener('click', function () { controller(aboutBtn); });
  projectBtn.addEventListener('click', function () { controller(projectBtn); });
}();
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#yourApp div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#aboutDiv {
  background: pink;
}

#projectDiv {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="yourApp">
  <div id='aboutDiv' class='show'></div>
  <div id='projectDiv' class='hide'></div>
  
  <button id="aboutBtn">About</button>
  <button id="projectBtn">Project</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The switching between the two buttons are correct, but I also want it to be able to (in your example) to toggle between the colors when I click on the the same button,

Like:
1st click -  opens div
2nd click - closes div
3rd click  - opens div

Comment: In that case you just do something like what I've done above.. Only you set the class-name property to 'hide' in the example I provided.

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks!!

Comment: Hope my most recent update is as helpful as possible, I even included comments in that version.